# Detecting underflow during execution

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, g++

Is there any way to detect underflow automatically during execution?

Specifically I believe there should be a compiler option to generate code that checks for underflows and similar falgs right after mathematical operations that could cause them.

I'm talking about the G++ compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C99/C++11 have floating point control functions (e.g. `fetestexcept`) and defined flags (including `FE_UNDERFLOW`) that should let you detect floating point underflow reasonably portably (i.e., with any compiler/library that supports these).

Though they're not as portable, gcc has an `feenableexcept` that will let you set floating point exceptions that are trapped. When one of the exceptions you've enabled fires, your program will receive a `SIGFPE` signal.

At least on most hardware, there's no equivalent for integer operations -- an underflow simply produces a 2's complement (or whatever) result and (for example) sets the the flags (e.g., carry and sign bits) to signal what happened. C99/C++11 do have some flags for things like integer overflow, but I don't believe they're nearly as widely supported.

Comment: @Mehrdad - C++11 is the next C++ standard, currently being considered by the ISO member nations and expected to be accepted later this year. [http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3290.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3290.pdf)

Comment: @Bo: I thought that was C++0x?

Comment: @Merdad - That's the same one, except we now know what x is and the work is complete.

Comment: @Mehrdad: C++0x is the unofficial name until it becomes a standard. I'll carry on calling it that until I know for sure it won't be C++12.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was searching for! Moreover that signal can then be handled programmatically: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/csignal/signal/