# How to detect double precision floating point overflow and underflow?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have following variables:

```
double dblVar1;
double dblVar2;
```

They may have big values but less than `double` max.

I have various arithmetic on above variables like addition, multiplication and power:

```
double dblVar3 = dblVar1 * dblVar2; 
double dblVar4 = dblVar1 + dblVar2;
double dblVar5 = pow(dblVar1, 2);
```

In all above I have to check overflow and underflow. How can I achieve this in C++?

Comment: do you want to find out what value would cause overflow?

Comment: @ cf16 I am looking for sample code how to check for overflow and underflow on arthimetic operatoins on double.

Comment: Check for values of +/-Inf

Comment: @JimBalter: that would find overflow, but what about underflow?

Comment: @JimBalter double/int doesn't make a difference in this case...

Comment: @Syjin That's absurd.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752232/detecting-underflow-during-execution

Comment: @Syjin: it certainly does make a difference!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Please explain why. I thought, that in this case it is irrelevant. But maybe I'm totally wrong.

Comment: @Syjin You're totally wrong. It's up to you to explain why you think it makes no difference when it obviously does.

Comment: @Syjin: because integers (usually) display wraparound behaviour on overflow, floating-point saturates at infinity.  And integers don't have underflow.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth ah I see... thank you for the explanation and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Syjin Also the link you cited doesn't address how to deal with overflow on multiplication and pow as given in this question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A lot depends on context.  To be perfectly portable, you have to
check *before* the operation, e.g. (for addition):

```
if ( (a < 0.0) == (b < 0.0)
    && std::abs( b ) > std::numeric_limits<double>::max() - std::abs( a ) ) {
    //  Addition would overflow...
}
```

Similar logic can be used for the four basic operators.

If all of the machines you target support IEEE (which is 
probably the case if you don't have to consider mainframes), you
can just do the operations, then use `isfinite` or `isinf` on
the results.

For underflow, the first question is whether a gradual underflow
counts as underflow or not.  If not, then simply checking if the
results are zero and `a != -b` would do the trick.  If you want
to detect gradual underflow (which is probably only present if
you have IEEE), then you can use `isnormal`—this will
return false if the results correspond to gradual underflow.
(Unlike overflow, you test for underflow *after* the operation.)

Comment: @ James what if a >0.0 and b >0.0 how do we check for overflow here

Comment: @venkysmarty With the expresion I posted.  It works for all cases (for addition).

Comment: `isnormal(5.0 - 5.0)` is false, making it appear like there is an underflow in the subtraction. I am unsure whether the OP wants this subtraction pointed out as underflow (actually, I am unsure what the OP means by “checking [for] underflow”).

Comment: @PascalCuoq That seems strange to me.  (And I'm also unsure what exactly he's trying to do with regards to underflow.)

Comment: Floating-point underflow does not occur due to subtraction. But it can occur, for example, due to multiplication by a number close to zero or division by a number far from zero.

Answer (score 11):

POSIX, C99, C++11 have `<fenv.h>` (and `<cfenv>` for C++11) which have functions to test the IEEE754 exceptions flags (which have nothing to do with C++ exceptions, it would be too easy):

```
int  feclearexcept(int);
int  fegetexceptflag(fexcept_t *, int);
int  feraiseexcept(int);
int  fesetexceptflag(const fexcept_t *, int);
int  fetestexcept(int);
```

The flag is a bitfield with the following bits defined:

```
FE_DIVBYZERO
FE_INEXACT
FE_INVALID
FE_OVERFLOW
FE_UNDERFLOW
```

So you can clear them before the operations and then test them after.  You'll have to check the documentation for the effect of library functions on them.

Comment: The macros specifying the bit fields are only conditionally supported; not all systems will have them.  (And I can't find in the standard where it specifies the meaning of `FF_UNDERFLOW`.  In IEEE, does it include gradual underflow or not?)

Comment: @JamesKanze IEEE-754 does support unnormalized values (that is, gradual underflow).

Comment: @JamesKanze, it is defined in IEEE 754.  From memory, it allows the implementation to choose between several semantics, but ISTR that for all of them FE_UNDERFLOW is raised when generating denormals if the result is not exact (if I'm not mistaken, the lenience is about detecting the situation before or after rounding).

Comment: @AProgrammer Yes.  And `FF_UNDERFLOW` is defined as simply reflecting whatever the hardward does ("exception" in the sense used in the IEEE standard), so you should get it when gradual underflow occurs.  (Whether this is what is wanted or not is another question.)

Comment: @AProgrammer - just a little quibble: the latest version of IEEE 754 has replaced "denormal" with "subnormal".

Answer (score 9):

With a decent compiler (which supports the newest C++ standard), you can use [these](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/fetestexcept) functions:

```
#include <cfenv>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::feclearexcept(FE_OVERFLOW);
    std::feclearexcept(FE_UNDERFLOW);

    double overflowing_var = 1000;
    double underflowing_var = 0.01;

    std::cout << "Overflow flag before: " << (bool)std::fetestexcept(FE_OVERFLOW) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Underflow flag before: " << (bool)std::fetestexcept(FE_UNDERFLOW) << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        overflowing_var *= overflowing_var;
        underflowing_var *= underflowing_var;
    }

    std::cout << "Overflow flag after: " << (bool)std::fetestexcept(FE_OVERFLOW) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Underflow flag after: " << (bool)std::fetestexcept(FE_UNDERFLOW) << std::endl;
}

/** Output:
  Overflow flag before: 0
  Underflow flag before: 0
  Overflow flag after: 1
  Underflow flag after: 1
 */
```

Comment: @ ulidtko above code doesnot compile on VS2008 as I am getting cannot open cfenv file error. How can I overcome this situation. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

ISO C99 defines functions to query and manipulate the floating-point status word. You can use these functions to check for untrapped exceptions when it's convenient, rather than worrying about them in the middle of a calculation.

It provides

```
FE_INEXACT
FE_DIVBYZERO
FE_UNDERFLOW
FE_OVERFLOW
FE_INVALID
```

For example

```
   {
       double f;
       int raised;
       feclearexcept (FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
       f = compute ();
       raised = fetestexcept (FE_OVERFLOW | FE_INVALID);
       if (raised & FE_OVERFLOW) { /* ... */ }
       if (raised & FE_INVALID) { /* ... */ }
       /* ... */
     }
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Status-bit-operations.html