# How to detect integer overflow in int64 variables with X++

Tags: overflow, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Is there a reliable way to detect integer overflow in int64 variables with X++?

Example:

```
int64 n;

n = 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;

n += 1;

info(int642str(n));
```

Reference:

[Integers [AX 2012]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa851966.aspx)

[How to detect double precision floating point overflow and underflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655070/how-to-detect-double-precision-floating-point-overflow-and-underflow)

Answer (score 0):

Adapted code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655070/how-to-detect-double-precision-floating-point-overflow-and-underflow):

```
int64 a, b;

#localmacro.ABS_INT
    (%1 < 0 ? 0 - %1 : %1)
#endmacro

a = 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;

b = 1;



if ( ((a < 0) == (b < 0)) && (#ABS_INT(b) > int64Max() - #ABS_INT(a)))
{        
    throw error(strFmt("Integer overflow in %1.", funcName()));    
}    

a += b;

info(int642str(a));
```