# Visual Studio always breaking on "Floating-point inexact result"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, exception

So this is happening in both VS 2015 and 2017. Every time I run my application, it constantly breaks on `Floating-point inexact result` exception in `msvcrt.dll`, and if I click `Continue`, the exception comes up again and again. I unchecked it from `Exception Settings`, but I can't seem to be able to get to stop it from halting no matter what I try.

This is what I am getting:

[image: Floating-point inexact result]

Enabling or disabling `Just My Code` seems to have no effect, and this issue is occurring also in Visual Studio 2015 for me.

How do I resolve this, please?

Comment: Never mind breaking, why is this throwing? That's not default behavior.

Comment: Floating-point exceptions are signaled by an arithmetic exception trap. These exceptions include:
Invalid operation, division by zero, overflow, underflow, inexact result, integer overflow.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226618%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 
Masking floating point exceptions has no effect. You need find out what exactly causes this exception in your code and fix it.

Comment: Isn't floating point pretty much always inexact? That's not a fixable property, is it?

Comment: I still don’t think an arithmetic exception could be masked by some settings in VS. But you can use these function mentioned on this answer to check them:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15655796/9125096

Answer (score 0):

[This website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/controlfp-s?view=vs-2019#remarks) states:

> By default, the run-time libraries mask all floating-point exceptions.

It seems to me that your code changes this default by using one or several functions belonging to a group of functions named `_clearfp(...)`, `_controlfp(...)` or `_controlfp_s(...)`.

The solution to the problem is to set the interrupt exception mask _MCW_EM to the default value. For more information on the mask constants and values visit [this website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/control87-controlfp-control87-2?view=vs-2019#control-word-masks-and-values).

You can use the following code to set _MCW_EM to the default value:

```
    //Read
    unsigned int fp_control = 0;
    _controlfp_s(&fp_control, 0, 0);
    //Make changes
    unsigned int new_fp_control = fp_control | _EM_INVALID | _EM_DENORMAL | _EM_ZERODIVIDE | _EM_OVERFLOW | _EM_UNDERFLOW | _EM_INEXACT;
    //Update
    _controlfp_s(&fp_control, new_fp_control, _MCW_EM);
```

This code should fix the problem.