# What's the least possible denominator/divisor value?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a code to prevent the zero denominator/divisor to avoid NaN value as a result of the division.

I wonder what could be the least possible denominator value in double in C++ and how to find or what's the reason for that?

Comment: Are you asking how to detect if a division will result in overflow? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655070/how-to-detect-double-precision-floating-point-overflow-and-underflow

Comment: @It'scominghome, Epsilon isn't quite right. The step to the next value after 1 isn't the same thing as the step to the next value after 0. For me, the difference between the two is quite pronounced (e-16 vs. e-308).

Comment: What exactly are you doing to avoid NaN? Simply replacing a zero divisor with a small (positive) value is not necessarily a correct approach (it depends on the context). A more correct approach might be to deal with NaN rather than avoiding it.

Comment: @JaMiT Thanks for pointing this out. For my application, just avoiding NaN is clearly not enough. It moves result out of the proper path.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the smallest positive<sup>(a)</sup> normalised `double` in C++ can be obtained with `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` (from the `<limits>` header).

However, while you *may* be able to use that to prevent `NaN` values<sup>(b)</sup>, it probably won't help with overflows. For example:

```
std::numeric_limits<double>::max() / 1.0 => ok
std::numeric_limits<double>::max() / 0.5 => overflow
```

Preventing that will depend on both the denominator *and* the numerator.

As for *why* that is the case, it's because C++ uses IEEE-754 double-precision format for its `double` types - it's a limitation of that format.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I've chosen positive values here, the smallest value *could* be interpreted as the most negative, in which case it would be read as `-std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`. But, given your intent is to avoid `NaN`, I suspect my assumption is correct.

<sup>(b)</sup> I'm not entirely sure *how* you intend to do this, which is why I also discuss overflows - you may want to make it clearer in your question.

Answer (score -1):

The smallest possible float is 1.17549e-38.  To expand upon It's coming home's comment, see the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295693/whats-the-least-possible-denominator-divisor-value):

```
#include <limits>

//...

std::numeric_limits<float>::max();  // 3.40282e+38
std::numeric_limits<float>::min();  // 1.17549e-38
std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
```

The `float` in the above code can be replaced by any data type you want, ie:

```
std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
```

Comment: The exact maximum and minimum for 'float' isn't set by the standard. Implementations can use any conforming floating point representation.